# Google Contacts Sync with Database

Tags: php, laravel, web, synchronization, google-contacts-api

I couldn't find any documentation on this.

I'm making a web app where the user can sync all of his google contacts with users within the database. (Retrieves all of the users contacts and stores them in the database then retrieves the non imported ones and stores them in their contacts without duplicates.) I've managed to do that part but I can only sync them via database, If I created or delete a user from the database the same is done with the user in the google contacts list.

Is there a way to do it through google contacts?

User **DELETES** contact from google contact list **--->** User **DELETED** from database.

Thank you.

Comment: did you get this resolved? if yes, please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through synchronization interval and schedule this task to run based on specific events, you will need to know the source of your contacts (Web  App, Google).
In your event action do the following

- Retrieve the Only contact's with google source.
- Add the new contacts wasn't exist before in your DB
- Remove the contacts which exist in your database with source=google but not exist more in google feed.

**Example:**

Your database have the following contacts

```
ID       Name          Source
1        Joe Adam      Google
2        Julia Mark    Google
3        Adam Hankins  Google
```

Now, Call the Google contacts API to check updates or deleted actions
if you find this contact not exist anymore so delete from your database as well.